# Google Image Search Path

Tags: image, seo

SEO Question, if the images on a server are allowed to be index, named wisely with descriptive names and aren't oversized does the image path or folder make a difference for the ranking of that image in google image search?

Eg, Is pic A ranked higher than pic B (below) - if so, why?

A: /images/cat-on-a-chair.jpg
B: /images/repository/cat-on-a-chair.jpg

thanks

Comment: SEO questions will fit better in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

It'd be too difficult to run a controlled case study on a factor that, if it did help, would be too miniscule to notice.

The short answer: it's highly unlikely.

Think of the image itself and the page the image is found on as two completely separate entities (they are, indeed). When you do a Google Image search, you are finding pages that contain that image. So a highly-ranked page is likely going to be a good candidate for image results. *You aren't actually being returned direct images.*

Other things that influence ranking for images would include image-specific data like ALT tags, description, the image name, and so forth.

For reference, here are paths for top five results for `horses`:

- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Points_of_a_horse.jpg/330px-Points_of_a_horse.jpg
- http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Horse-and-pony.jpg/310px-Horse-and-pony.jpg
- http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/23500000/horse-horses-23582505-1024-768.jpg
- http://www.hedweb.com/animimag/horses-gallop.jpg
- http://www.horsesmaine.com/images/2%20%20horses.jpg

Scientifically, that's such a small sample that it's not worth mentioning. But let's assume it is: the majority of the results don't have relevant keywords in a directory path. Instead, a very highly-ranked website gets the first few positions.

If you wanted to take this further you could write a script to get a bigger sample, but at this point I'm hoping you've arrived at the conclusion that no, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts Zachary - This is useful.